# How to stitch(concat) two transport stream with two different resolution and I-frame slices format without loosing resolution and slices information

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I have been trying to test a use case with steam captured from multimedia device and that didn't work. And then I have been trying to create this specific transport stream for like two days now without success, so requesting some help.

I need to create transport stream with two different resolution and two different slicing format.

I divided the task in following steps and in last two steps I need help.

**Step 1** : Download sample video with resolution : 1920x1080.
             I downloaded [big buck bunny mp4](http:///http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4) .

**Step 2** : Create transport stream with following
resolution : 1920x720, H264 I frame slices per frame: 1
I used following ffmpeg commands to do that.

```
#Rename file to input.mp4
$ mv bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4 input.mp4
#Extract transport stream
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy first.ts
```

first.ts is having 1980x720 resolution and one H264 I slice per frame.

**Step 3** : Create another transport stream with smaller resolution using following commands

```
#Get mp4 with lower resolution.
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 640x480 temp.mp4
#Extract trans port stream from mp4
$ ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -c copy low_r.ts
```

**Step 4** : Edit(and re-encode?) low_r.ts to have two H264 I frame slices.
I used following command to achieve it.

```
$ x264 --slices 4 low_r.ts -o second.ts
```

However when I play this second.ts on vlc using following command it doesn't play

```
$ vlc ./second.ts
```

And using Elacard StreamEye software when I analyze the transport stream I see that it has 4 `H264 I slices` in only two times other than that lot of `H264 p slices` and `H264 B slices`. 
**Need help here to figure out why second.ts doesn't play and why slicing is not correct.**

**Step 5** : Combine both the transport stream without loosing resolution and slicing information.
Don't know command for this. Need help here.
I tried ffmpeg but that combines two stream with different resolution and makes one file with one resolution.

Any suggestions/pointers would help me proceed. Let me also know if any of the above steps are not fine too.